# Using wp_insert_post with WP Network in a cron script

Tags: multisite, wp-insert-post

I have network of sites, and I need to import data into them via a cron job. Obviously `wp_insert_post` is meaningless in this case, since i'm not in a blog...i'm in a cron script.
I also read that `switch_to_blog` is deprecated, yet I can't find any alternative.
How do I set the blog to post to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch_to_blog isn't deprecated anymore. You can use it just fine. However, it does have a bit of overhead, so you want to use it as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution is much easier than this....`$wpdb->set_blog_id($blog_id);`
does exactly what I need it to do.